# Why do I get "405: Method Not Allowed" when I send a POST request with Perl's REST::Client, but not with Perl's LWP::UserAgent or Python?

Tags: python, perl, rest, post, http-status-code-405

When I send a POST request with Perl's [`REST::Client`](https://metacpan.org/pod/REST::Client), I get the following response:

```
405: Method Not Allowed
```

However, when I send a POST request to the same URL with Perl's [`LWP::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent) or Python's `Requests`, I get a "success" response. GET requests work with both `REST::Client` and Python.

How can I fix this?

---

Here's the code that uses `REST::Client` (returns HTTP 405):

```
use REST::Client;
use JSON;
$header = {
    'Auth' => '04211b77df',
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Content-type' => 'application/json'
};

%body = (
    'sid' => '001',
    'pid' => 'c7b3d83',
    'file' => [
        {
            'name' => 'file1.txt',
            'location' => 'folderA'
        },
        {
            'name' => 'file2.txt',
            'location' => 'folderB'
        }
    ]
);

$client = REST::Client->new();
$client->POST('URL', encode_json(\%body), $header);
```

Here's the code that uses `LWP::UserAgent` (returns HTTP 200):

```
#!/use/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Data::Dumper;
use JSON;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new; 
my $req = HTTP::Request->new(POST => 'URL');

$req->header('Auth' => '04211b77df');
$req->header('Content-type' => 'application/json');
$req->header('Accept' => 'application/json');

my %body = (
    'sid' => '001',
    'pid' => 'c7b3d83',
    'file' => [
        {
            'name' => 'file1.txt',
            'location' => 'folderA'
        },
        {
            'name' => 'file2.txt',
            'location' => 'folderB'
        }
    ]
);
$req->content(encode_json(\%body));
$ua->request($req);
```

Here's the Python code (returns HTTP 200):

```
import requests, json, sys
headers = {
    'Auth': '04211b77df'
    'Accept': 'application/json'
    'Content-type': 'application/json'
}
data={
    'sid': '001',
    'pid': 'c7b3d83',
    'file': [
        {
            'name': 'file1.txt',
            'location': 'folderA'
        },
        {
            'name': 'file2.txt',
            'location': 'folderB'
        }
    ]
}

requests.request('POST', 'URL', data=data, headers=headers)
```

Comment: You'll need to [edit] your question to include a [mcve] if you expect to receive any useful answers.

Comment: If you are able to get a successful result from one client, and fail with another, I would look at the clients, not the server. Fire up wireshark and watch the traffic from both clients, and look for the discrepancy.

Comment: As a side note, you should `use strict; use warnings 'all';` in every Perl script you write.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire thanks will try it out

Comment: `encode_json` is almost certainly not what you want there. The endpoint is probably expecting the parameters to be URL encoded (e.g. `a=1&b=2`)

Comment: Okay, I *think* I see the issue. (REST::Client actually uses LWP::UserAgent behind the scenes, so your latest edit helped narrow things down a lot.) REST::Client is calling [`$ua->simple_request`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#ua-simple_request-request) instead of `$ua->request`: "The difference from `request()` is that `simple_request()` will not try to handle redirects or authentication responses." I'm guessing authentication is getting in the way. I think this is a bug in REST::Client. Voted to reopen your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your REST::Client code and your LWP::UserAgent code generate nearly identical requests.* However, REST::Client, which uses LWP::UserAgent under the hood, sends the request with `$ua->simple_request()`, while your LWP::UserAgent code uses `$ua->request()`.

According to the [documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP::UserAgent#ua-simple_request-request):

> The difference from `request()` is that `simple_request()` will not try to handle redirects or authentication responses.

I'm guessing authentication is causing the issue. I'm also guessing that the API you're using doesn't require authentication for GET requests, since you said those are working with REST::Client.

---

To fix, set the [`follow`](https://metacpan.org/pod/REST::Client#follow) option to `1` in the constructor:

```
my $client = REST::Client->new(follow => 1);
```

or call the `setFollow` method:

```
my $client = REST::Client->new();
$client->setFollow(1);
```

This will handle authentication responses properly, but it will also follow redirects. Unfortunately, you can't set the behavior for redirects and authentication independently, which is a [long-standing bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=65804).

---

* The only difference is that REST::Client adds a `Content-length` header, which I don't think matters.

Dump of REST::Client request before sending:

```
$VAR1 = bless( { 
                 '_content' => '{"sid":"001","pid":"c7b3d83","file":[{"location":"folderA","name":"file1.txt"},{"location":"folderB","name":"file2.txt"}]}',
                 '_uri' => bless( do{\(my $o = 'http://www.example.com')}, 'URI::http' ),
                 '_headers' => bless( { 
                                        'auth' => '04211b77df',
                                        'content-type' => 'application/json',
                                        'accept' => 'application/json',
                                        'content-length' => 122,
                                        '::std_case' => { 
                                                          'auth' => 'Auth'
                                                        }
                                      }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
                 '_method' => 'POST'
               }, 'HTTP::Request' );
```

Dump of LWP::UserAgent request before sending:

```
$VAR1 = bless( { 
                 '_content' => '{"sid":"001","pid":"c7b3d83","file":[{"location":"folderA","name":"file1.txt"},{"location":"folderB","name":"file2.txt"}]}',
                 '_uri' => bless( do{\(my $o = 'http://www.example.com')}, 'URI::http' ),
                 '_headers' => bless( { 
                                        'auth' => '04211b77df',
                                        'content-type' => 'application/json',
                                        'accept' => 'application/json',
                                        '::std_case' => { 
                                                          'auth' => 'Auth'
                                                        }
                                      }, 'HTTP::Headers' ),
                 '_method' => 'POST'
               }, 'HTTP::Request' );
```

There will be other minor differences when the requests are actually sent, like the user-agent string, but I don't think they're related to your problem.